# Same height of two different div's children

Tags: html, css

I have two `divs` (`.item`) and each of them have the same number of `divs` (`.sub-item`) as children. The content of those `.sub-items` may have different height as shown below:

```css
.content-3-container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  float: left;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

.sub-item {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-3-container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="sub-item">
      <span>Sub-Content 1</span>
      <br/>
      <span>Sub-Content 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      <span>Sub-Content 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="sub-item">
      <span>Sub-Content 4</span>
    </div>
    <div class="sub-item">
      <span>Sub-Content 5</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is how do I make the height of the `sub-item` that has `Sub-Content 1` and `Sub-Content 2`same as that of the `sub-item` that has `Sub-Content 4`?

Comment: You can't with flexbox. It has no method if equalising heights that do not share a parent element.

Comment: some js code may solve this. This can not be done dynamically just with css. There can be more than 5 items, right?

Comment: Make subitem also flex with grow 1?